# ID column into the 'link to item' of a list

Tags: list, column

In a list, how would I make the ID column the column that links to the item's detail screen?

Answer (score 2):

It is worth noting that if you are using SharePoint 2013 you need to use

```
linkToItem="TRUE"
```

Instead of

```
LinkToItem="TRUE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the AllItems.aspx page for the specific list.
Search for the  tag
List item LinkToItem="TRUE" to ID column you want the link:

```
<ViewFields><br/>
<FieldRef Name="Attachments"/><br/>
<FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/><br/>
<FieldRef Name="ID" LinkToItem="TRUE"/><br/>
<FieldRef Name="data_x0020_column"/><br/>
<FieldRef Name="Another_x0020_column"/><br/></ViewFields>
```

Comment: Open the page for the specific list in where?

Comment: Use SharePoint Designer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978769/can-i-customize-add-edit-page-for-list-in-sharepoint